# Custom Tabited.Header Style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want tot use only pictures in the header of the `tabcontrol`.
I'm using like this:

```
<TabItem.Header>
   <Image Name="ImageClientPoints"  Width="150" Height="80"
          Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</TabItem.Header>
```

and the result is the following:

http://oi39.tinypic.com/x3hnc9.jpg

but I want only the picture without the grey content around the picture.

I'm new to wpf i read about it and as I know I have to create a `datatemplate` for this but it's to hard to me yet, an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. It seems header have some kind of padding reserved. So `set the margin value to some negative value` to overlap that padding space.

This will do for you -

```
<TabItem.Header>
   <Image Name="ImageClientPoints"  Width="150" Height="80"
          Stretch="Fill" Margin="-5" />
</TabItem.Header>
```

OR

```
<TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Image Name="ImageClientPoints"  Width="150" Height="80"
             Stretch="Fill" Margin="-5" />
   </DataTemplate>
</TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: Worked for me though. Try setting some higher value say `-10` and see if that helps.

Comment: It's working thanks, but I want a data template for this because when my tab item headers doesn't fit's the width of my screen the following happens: http://postimg.org/image/orvjcc4dj/

Comment: That's default behaviour of tabControl if tab item's width height grow beyond window's width. `DataTemplate` won't solve this thing for you.

Comment: Glad to help. I have added the `DataTemplate` approach as well but as i mentioned it won't do anything fancy either.